# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': Value at index 0 does not have a transferable type

Tags: javascript, web-worker, worker, postmessage, transferable

This is the code of my worker:

```
onmessage = function (event) {
    postMessage({'data': event.data}, ['http://localhost:9000']);
};
```

And this is the code where I use the worker:

```
var worker = new Worker("/path/to/my/worker.js");
worker.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log("RECEIVED: ", event.data);
};
worker.onerror = function (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', err)
};
worker.postMessage({'data': 'blabla', 'msg': 'Hi'});
```

But when the postMessage in the worker code is called, it gives me this error:
"Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': Value at index 0 does not have a transferable type."

I've tried also to serialize the object with this code:

```
onmessage = function (event) {
        postMessage(JSON.stringify({'data': event.data}), ['http://localhost:9000']);
    };
```

But nothing has changed.

------  EDIT  ----------------------------------------------------------------

I tried the following code in the worker file:

```
function count() {
    var i = 0;
    self.onmessage = function (event) {
        postMessage("Hello " + event.data);
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        postMessage(i);
    }
    postMessage("Finished");
}

count();
```

The postMessage inside the onmessage function is the only one which gives me an error.

Answer (score 6):

The second parameter of `Worker.postMessage()` is meant to hold a list of objects of which you want to transfer ownership to your main window. This is restricted to some specific types (mostly `ArrayBuffer`s and `Bitmap`s).

Explaining the error message: Your second parameter is `["some string"]` with `"some string"` at index `0` and JS believes you want to transfer that object (which obviously wasn't your intention).

Just remove `['http://localhost:9000']` and you should be fine.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage for details and examples.

Comment: Also, have a look here to know which objects you can pass as second argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable.